# R equivalent of `with...end with` in BASIC

Tags: r, with-statement

I am looking for a R function similar to the `with...end with` statement in BASIC, i.e., instead of

```
x = list()
x$a = 1
x$b = 2
x$c = 3
...
```

You can do something like:

```
with x; do 
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
...
end with
```

I remember doing this before, but can't remember the name of the function anymore, arghhh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `within` for something like this

```
x = list()
x <- within(x, {
   a <- 1
   b <- 2
   c <- 3
})
x
```